# Looping functions together for an FSM

Tags: python, function, fsm

As many of you have probably seen and/or coded, I'm trying to make a finite state machine; 5 states and 9 transitions, to determine if someone is laughing. I don't necesarrily want the entire answer, cuz I do want to figure out as much as I can by myself. However, the professors and TA's aren't always very quick or helpful when answering, and this place is way more useful anyway.

I just want to be able to type "ha" or "ho" until a "!" is entered, saying "you laughed." Any other characters will end it. There are 3 functions to make; the get_ch(), the find_state(), and the main(), which drives both of the other ones. Here's what I have:

```
def get_ch():  # prompt for the input in a loop
    ch = input("Enter a character or press the Return key to finish: ")
    if len(ch) > 1: 
        print("Invalid input, please try again.")
    else:
        return ch

def find_state(state, ch):
    if state==1:
        if ch=="h" or ch=="H":
            state=2
            return state
        else:
            state=5
            return state
    if state==2:
        if ch=="a" or ch=="A" or ch=="o" or ch=="O":
            state=3
            return state
        else:
            state=5
            return state
    if state==3:
        if ch=="!":
            state=4
            return state
        if ch=="h" or ch=="H":
            state=2
            return state
        else:
            state=5
            return state

def main():
    print("I can recognize if you are laughing or not.")
    print("Please enter one character at a time.")

    # initialize the variables, for example:
    ch=get_ch()
    string=""
    state=1

    #call the functions in a loop

    while get_ch():
        if len(ch)<1:
            print("\nYou entered", string)
            print("You are laughing.")
            print("You are not laughing.")
        else:
            if state<4:
               find_state(state,ch)
               string+=ch
               continue
            if state==4:
                  print("\nYou entered", string)
                  print("You are laughing.")
            else:
                  print("\nYou entered", string)
                  print("You are not laughing.")
main()
```

The issue I'm having is that the functions aren't "talking" to each other. I don't know if this is because they are not properly looped in the main() or if the issue lies within the individual functions themselves (such as calling back on get_ch() while in find_state()).

Comment: Looks like your indentation got messed up when you pasted your code here.

Comment: Looks a little like you'd like to use coroutines - that is 'jumping back and forth between two functions without `return`'. It's doable, but a little more involved than 'intro-level' Python. Check eg [this](https://juliank.wordpress.com/2013/01/11/recursive-descent-in-python-using-generators/).

Comment: Should be better now. I always do that when I copy from Spyder... and subsequently always forget to double check it. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot use coroutines or trampolines; we just have to loop the 2 functions within the main function.

Comment: When you write `while get_ch():`, you are *throwing away the return value*.  It doesn't magically end up in your `ch` variable just because it was called `ch` inside the function, or because you previously assigned the result of the first call of this function to `ch`.

Comment: Realized I wasn't getting the ch returned properly, nor was I returning the state properly either. The final product looked way different than this. The find_state() needed simply return "Return X" where X=state. Also, having ch=get_ch() in the main() would call on it to run once by itself before the rest of the main() started.